# how to get the text from a data bounded listbox by index

Tags: c#, listbox

In a windows application i have two listBox + one checked listbox. The user should check some items in checked-listbox and the value of items in listbox 1 & 2 with same indexes  of checked listbox should get and show in some text boxes.
I have written this code but the returned value is something like `System.Data.DataRowView`

```
int a = servicelist.CheckedItems.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
     int total;
     int b = servicelist.CheckedIndices[i];
     textbox1.text += listbox1.items[i].tostring();
     textbox2.text += listbox2.items[i].tostring();
}
```

Comment: You should try `listbox1.items[i].Value.ToString()` or something.

Comment: How did you bind the ListBox? What are its `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` (did you set any?).

Answer (score 0):

Display Member & Value member are same like this

```
  listBox1.DataSource = dsprice.Tables["price"];
       listBox1.DisplayMember = "price";
       listBox1.ValueMember = "price";
```

Answer (score 0):

i could solve this by this code

```
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {

            int b = servicelist.CheckedIndices[i];

            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)listBox1.Items[b];
            string itemT = drv.Row["price"].ToString();
```